how to edit only the color of a page
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{geometry,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[placement=bottom,scale=1,opacity=1]{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \fill [red] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)!.25!(current page.south east)$) coordinate (a);
      \fill [blue] (current page.south west) rectangle (a);
    \end{tikzpicture}}}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{pagecolor,afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{put}{b}{}{1.01in}
\DeclareFixedFont{\subtitlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{}{0.5in}
\DeclareFixedFont{\subsubtitlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{}{0.3in}
\afterpage{\restoregeometry}
\newgeometry{left=1.5cm, right=1cm,top=1cm, bottom=1cm}
\definecolor{mytan}{HTML}{F6D5A8}
\pagecolor{SpringGreen}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\titlefont\textcolor{yellow}{Notes}
\vspace{4cm}\\
\subsubtitlefont{Benjamín Garcés}
\vspace{1cm}\\
\subtitlefont{RING THEORY}
\vspace{1cm}\\
\subsubtitlefont{First Edition}

\end{center}
\newpagecolor{red}
\afterpage{\afterpage{\restorepagecolor}}

\chapter{Introduction to Module Theory}
\end{document}

I'm trying to create a front page with colors. I found this code to be able to paint half of a page with one color and the other half with a different one, the problem is that all the following pages were like this, and I want them to be white. I've tried \newpagecolor, \pagecolor{white} and it hasn't worked for me.

Pls provide a compilable code with \documentclass[]{}, preambule and \begin{document} ... \end{document}

Sorry, i dont know how to copy my code. I updated it there, that's what I have. after that comes just text and finally the end{document}

It is advised to remove the multiple uses of packages and then minimize the packages not required. Additionally it appears " cor " is defined twice. One of which is in \newtcbtheorem and the other in \newcommand .

Thanks for the suggestion, do you know how to help me with what I need?

Welcome or welcome back or ...! You're missing \end{document}, but you should also try to minimise the code you post here to demonstrate the problem by removing preamble we don't need to reproduce it.

This code is smaller and you can compile it, there you will see that on the second page where chapter 1 begins, the page continues with the blue and red design

How are you compiling this? If I compile with pdfTeX, I get an error telling me to use a unicode engine. If I compile with luaTeX, I get an error telling me pdfTeX version 1.40 or later is needed. If I compile with xeTeX, I get an error complaining that \cor is already defined (see @Leucippus's comment above). If I ignore that error, it fails because I do not have unnamed.jpg ....

The \cor command no longer appears, and the unnamed.jpg photo is no longer there. I am using overleaf

Off-topic: as well as including packages multiple times, you're loading conflicting packages. If you're using a unicode engine, drop fontenc, lmodern etc. If you're not, drop unicode-math. Regardless of engine, drop inputenc. You cannot need both lipsum and kantlipsum. In your real document, you should drop both.

If you have a relatively recent TeX, everypage is deprecated and you should use the new hooks instead.
Note that your font setup and packages involve multiple conflicts: you need to resolve these or they will bite you.
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% for pdfTeX or TeX only
% \usepackage{unicode-math}% for luaTeX or xeTeX only
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,top=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% don't load in your real document

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{SpringGreen}% not sure where you want this as it ends up behind the blocks of blue and red
\AddToHookNext {shipout/background} 
{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill [red] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)!.25!(current page.south east)$) coordinate (a);
    \fill [blue] (current page.south west) rectangle (a);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\AddToHookNext {shipout/after} 
{%
  \nopagecolor%\restoregeometry
}
\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{put}{b}{n}{1.01in}% pdfTeX or TeX
\DeclareFixedFont{\subtitlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{n}{0.5in}% pdfTeX or TeX
\DeclareFixedFont{\subsubtitlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{n}{0.3in}% pdfTeX or TeX
\begin{center}
  \titlefont\textcolor{yellow}{NOTES}
  \vspace{4cm}\\
  \subsubtitlefont{Benjamín Garcés}
  \vspace{1cm}\\
  \subtitlefont{ADVANCED RING THEORY}
  \vspace{1cm}\\
  \subsubtitlefont{First Edition}
\end{center}
\clearpage
\kant[1-5]% this is the sole purpose of loading kantlipsum
\end{document}

